# What is the efficient way to check two memoryviews in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, cython, typed-memory-views

I want to speed up my code by using memoryviews. here are two classes I use:

```
cdef class child:
    cdef public int[:] move
    def __init__(self, move):
        self.move = move

cdef class parent:
    cdef public:
        list children
        int[:, :] moves
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
    def add_children(self, moves):
        cdef int i = 0
        cdef int N = len(moves)
        for i in range(N):
            self.children.append(child(moves[i]))
```

And this is the code I want to check whether the classes work or not:

```
temp = []
for i in range(100):
    temp.append([i, i+1])

cdef int[:, :] moves = np.asarray(temp, dtype=np.int32)
a = parent()
a.add_children(moves)
for move in moves:
    for ch in a.children:
        if move == ch.move:
            print('ok')
```

I expect for 100 to print `ok` but I get nothing. I know if I use the `list(move) == list(ch.move)` I can get the expected output but I don't want the conversion overhead in loops.

Can anyone help me with an efficient way? If anyone has any other suggestion which improves the code speed, It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) (function that compares memory) from the c library:

```
from libc.string cimport memcmp

cdef int[:, :] moves = np.asarray(temp, dtype=np.int32)
cdef int[:] move
cdef child ch
a = parent()
a.add_children(moves)
for move in moves:
    for ch in a.children:
        if memcmp(&move[0], &ch.move[0], move.nbytes) == 0:
            print('ok')
```

However that could (probably) lead to problems if the memoryviews have different dtypes, endianness or strides - because `memcmp` just compares the plain memory.

Comment: Thank you bro that worked for me. I don't know much about `libc` library. Do you know any good books or tutorials which introduces some useful functions.

Comment: Not really, I never "formally" learned C (or C++) but sometimes I browse the [C++ reference documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) if I think there should be some function for a particular use-case and I use Cython or build a C extension on my own.

Comment: I see. you'd like to learn by experiencing it in actual project rather than keeping track of tutorials. That's the best way to learn programming I guess.

Comment: If I use this code in some file named `agent.pyx` and I use it in another file named `treesearch.py`, do I have to take care of sth in my code? I am asking it because I am already using `agent.py` file which works fine but is not fast enough and I want to speed up the code by `agent.pyx` mode. the `treesearch` file deals with Tkinter.

Comment: I also might try to use parallel computing. Does that have any conflicts with cython codes?

Comment: That depends on the details if there will be problems. Use locks or something similar if you deal with parallel computing (at least if you change values in a shared array). Probably better to ask a new question if and when you encounter problems. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use [`numpy.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html). (It accepts memoryviews as well as numpy arrays.)

```
if numpy.array_equal(move, ch.move):
  print("OK")
```

The main advantage over `memcmp` (that the other answer suggests) is that `memcmp` will not work on non-contiguous array (which the other answer admits). It's easy to get a non-contiguous memoryview just by taking a column of a 2D memoryview.

Comment: That's definitely the more general solution. But it's not the "most efficient" in this case - it's 50-100% slower (at least on my computer). :)

Comment: I'll check this one in my code too. the strange thing about the code is that I implement the same classes in pure python and I noticed the code in Cython was 10 times slower. I might ask it in another question.